# Laravel Eloquent, sort whereHas / width datas

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Here my code :

```
list($orderBy, $orderDirection) = explode('.', request()->get('sort_by'));

        $prestations = Prestation::with([
            'service' => function($query) { 
                $query->select(['id','name']);
            },
            'facility' => function($query) { 
                $query->select(['id','name']);
            },
            'conciergeries.network' => function($query) { 
                $query->select(['id','name']);
            }
        ])
            ->whereHas('service', function ($query) use ($searchService) {
                $query->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchService/i");
            })  
            ->whereHas('facility', function ($query) use ($searchPartenaire) {
                $query->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchPartenaire/i");
            })
            ->whereHas('conciergeries.network', function ($query) use ($searchFiliale) {
                $query->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchFiliale/i");
            })
                ->where('name', 'regexp', "/$search/i")
                ->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection)
                ->paginate(50);
```

I need to to an orderBy on `service.name` or `facility.name` or `conciergeries.network.name`, `$orderBy` and `$orderDirection` are coming from the view :

`$orderBy` can have this values : 'name', 'service', 'facility', 'filiale'.

`$orderDirection` can have this values : 'asc' or 'desc'.

I tried to add orderBy in the with query or in whereHas, but nothing works correctly.
Thank you very much.

Comment: This might not be the issue but why are you using `regexp` when you can probably just use `LIKE %searchval%` if you can just use a database collation with `ci` (case-insensitive)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add

```
'service' => function($query) use($orderBy, $orderDirection) { 
            $query->select(['id','name']);
            $query->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection)
        },
```

In with statements

Comment: "Undefined variable $orderBy" with your solution, i tried to add $orderBy and $orderDirection like this function($query, $orderBy, $orderDirection) but not a good result too.

Comment: It does not works too, no error but the sort is not correct.

Comment: Is the data is with upper case and lower case ?